# Pixel Coordinates in Openlayers

Tags: math, openlayers

In Google Maps each higher zoom level results in a resolution four times higher than the preceding level. For example, at zoom level 1, the map consists of 4 256x256 pixels tiles, resulting in a pixel space from 512x512. At zoom level 19, each x and y pixel on the map can be referenced using a value between 0 and 256 * 219.
What does Openlayers follow ?
Is this the formula that can be used to get the pixel coordinates from the world coordinates or extent ?
pixelCoordinate = worldCoordinate * 2 ( raised to power (zoomLevel))

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers is a framework for displaying maps, it's not specific to a single map. 
The pixel-to-map-unit depends on multiple things, e.g. your view projection, device pixel ratio or (of course) the zoom level.
The map unit does not even have to be a real world unit: You could build a map of Middle-Earth or the island of GTA.

**TL/DR** Don't bother, let that framework take care of that calculations. You probably asked this because of a specific question, so better ask that one here on StackOverflow.